# Barebones lightweight XMPP client for Windows?

Tags: windows, xmpp

I’ve been looking for a very simple, low footprint Windows XMPP client. So far, every client I’ve tried looks "full-featured", installs a bunch of libraries and uses 30 MB of RAM or more in task manager. I’ve tried Psi, Gajim, Pidgin, and Coccinella.

For comparison, some popular non-XMPP chat clients use less memory: mIRC uses only 15 MB of RAM, and Softros LAN Messenger uses 4 MB.

Isn’t there something more simple or an app that was designed/optimized for Windows specifically?

Comment: Is a GUI required, or would a [console-based XMPP client](http://superuser.com/a/468695/151741) be fine, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another Jabber client seems to fit my requirement, currently using 12MB ram as per task manager. It's windows-only, which is what I was looking for.

http://jajc.jrudevels.org/

Comment: Fell free to award yourself the answer. It will help others who find this question in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/).

Its a XMPP and VoIP client and it's lightweight as you want.
I was using it in Windows for almost a year and I never got more than 20MB of ram in task manager.

As a plus, I used other XMPP clients but neither of them has a easy configuration like Jitsi.